# Using custom templates for django admin urls

Tags: python, django

I've been looking around for couple of hours, yet I have found only old posts or complex explanations.

I customized the admin templates and now I have a left panel for side navigation and a right panel for content. I want to make the Django admin recognize my additional templates so that the navigation finally works where each button refers to an HTML template.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Using the URLconf defined in AdminDashWithNPMandBS.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/ [name='index']
admin/ login/ [name='login']
admin/ logout/ [name='logout']
admin/ password_change/ [name='password_change']
admin/ password_change/done/ [name='password_change_done']
admin/ jsi18n/ [name='jsi18n']
admin/ r/<int:content_type_id>/<path:object_id>/ [name='view_on_site']
admin/ auth/group/
admin/ auth/user/
admin/ ^(?P<app_label>auth)/$ [name='app_list']
The current path, admin/index.html, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: Just to mention , i m new to django

Comment: Did you just override the templates or you created custom views?

Comment: i overrided templates and static files only

Comment: So you created a folder called admin inside your templates and static folders, and files inside those folders that correspond to the names of the original files? I see the error you are getting, but need more info/context on how you got there. Are you able to access the admin at all?

Comment: hi , yes i did make a folder with the name "admin" etc, and yes i can access the admin , but i can't access html files independetly using url , admin/ will use index.html , but admin/index.html won't work as showed in the error , i guess it's a url problem and i ll need to override admin's AdminSite , the default admin views and so on? 
thanks for your time

Comment: hello , please check my recent question , it contains updates regarding my issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56385393/how-to-fix-django-admin-you-dont-have-permission-to-view-or-edit-anything