# how to fix django admin "You don't have permission to view or edit anything."?

Tags: python, django

for the sake of customizing the default admin site , i have made the following changes:

```
admin.py:

class CustomAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):

def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(CustomAdminSite, self).get_urls()
    custom_urls = [
        # re_path(r'^.*\.html', views.custom_admin_template_loader, name='custom-loader'),

        url(r'^.*\.html', self.admin_view(self.my_view), name="my-view"),
    ]
    return urls + custom_urls

def my_view(self, request):
    context = {}
    load_template = request.path.split('/')[-1]
    template = loader.get_template('admin/' + load_template)
    request.current_app = self.name
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

---

```
    apps.py:
from django.contrib.admin.apps import AdminConfig


class MyAdminConfig(AdminConfig):
    default_site = 'myproject.admin.CustomAdminSite'
```

---

```
settings.py:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myproject.apps.MyAdminConfig',
```

**nothing changed in urls.py**

**so if i access admin/ it works , but if i access another template using the view i made , it says You don't have permission to edit anything , how to fix it?**
for clarifications on WHY i m using that view, it is because i overrided the default admin templates and now i have a navigation bar , which means i need to navigate through different html files (templates)

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

i needed to pass context + set the request.current_app , (**added in my custom view**)

```
    context = {
        **self.each_context(request),
        'title': self.index_title,
        'app_list': app_list,
    }

    request.current_app = self.name
```

Comment: Can you put a working code. I am trying to do this but get an apps are not loaded yet. `apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready  raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.") django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.` It happens when i register my admin site in apps `'myproject.apps.MyAdminConfig',` in the installed apps.