# Unable to create a custom admin template url, getting errors Template errors & creating custom admin site errors

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I am using this blog:
https://medium.com/@adriennedomingus/adding-custom-views-or-templates-to-django-admin-740640cc6d42

Unable to make a custom template view in the Django Admin. I am getting `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet`

If I comment out the app in the settings.py, I get error `admin.site.register(Template, TemplateAdmin) NameError: name 'Template' is not defined`.

If I import the Template from django.templates then I get `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`

Unable to do:
1) custom_admin_site.register & 
2) models.Template is not found. Says there is no Template in models.

I have this on admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from django.templates import Template
class TemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = ‘admin/test_attempt.html’

admin.site.register(Template, TemplateAdmin)
```

if I register with CustomAdminSite then I get `register for model in model_or_iterable: TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable` error:

```
CustomAdminSite.register(Template, TemplateAdmin)

# Even the following doesnot work
# custom_site_admin.register(Template, TemplateAdmin)
```

I have this on views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

def preview(self, request, object_id):
    context = {}

    context = {
        **self.each_context(request),
        'title': self.index_title,
        # Unable to get this app_list as well
        # 'app_list': app_list,
    }

    request.current_app = self.name
    #load_template = request.path.split('/')[-1]
    #template = loader.get_template('admin/' + load_template)
    template = loader.get_template('admin/test_attempt.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

I have this on urls.py:

```
from .views import preview

class CustomAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(CustomAdminSite, self).get_urls()
    custom_urls = [
        path(r’^admin/test/(?P<object_id>\d+)$’, self.admin_view(preview), name=”preview”),
    ]
    return urls + custom_urls
```

I have this on my apps.py:

```
class CustomAdminSiteConfig(AdminConfig):
    default_site = 'batchexits.admin.CustomAdminSite'
```

I have added this in my settings.py registered apps:

```
'batchexits.admin.CustomAdminSiteConfig',
```

I have read this:
[how to fix django admin "You don't have permission to view or edit anything."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56385393/how-to-fix-django-admin-you-dont-have-permission-to-view-or-edit-anything)

Any help to get this working is appreciated.

Comment: What is `django.templates.Template` ? is that a Django model?

Comment: I couldn't even find the reference to `django.templates.Template` in the source code. Moreover, the **`admin.site.register(...)`** function should take the model class as the first argument, and in your case its not

Comment: Any ref is welcome. Even I could find the template in API. I have seen the django source and sure it doesnt work. Too much mystry on this concept. There is no blog around. It looks like an elephant task now without any Docs.

Comment: Arakkal Abu, the second issue is the django docs say it works. So I know it will

Comment: `from django.templates import Template` what are you trying to import here? 

usually the "Template" in  `admin.site.register(Template, TemplateAdmin)` should be a model class

Comment: Let me try this. It didn't work for me. I had import errors @bb4L

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure what it is you are trying to do, but it looks like you want a custom view added on to the standard django admin for a particular model. If this is the case you can leave `AdminSite` alone, you probably don't need to customise that at all. I have rearranged your code a bit, into something more like what it needs to be. I have not fixed everything because I'm not sure what it is you want, so don't copy and paste this, but I'll explain the relevant bits which will hopefully get you pointed in the right direction.

You shouldn't need to add anything to your apps in `settings.py`. The admin `django.contrib.admin` and hopefully your app us already listed as well (if not you will need to first add that, and then add your models before you think about adding an admin interface for them).

```
class TemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = ‘admin/test_attempt.html’   # 1

    def get_urls(self):  # 2
        urls = super().get_urls()
        admin_site = self.admin_site
        custom_urls = [
            path(
                r’^(?P<object_id>\d+)/test/$’,
                self.admin_view(self.preview),        # 3
                name="preview"),              
        ]
        return urls + custom_urls

    def preview(self, request, object_id): # 4 
        context = {}

        context = {
            **self.each_context(request),
            'title': self.index_title,
            # Unable to get this app_list as well
            # 'app_list': app_list,
        }

        request.current_app = self.name
        #load_template = request.path.split('/')[-1]
        #template = loader.get_template('admin/' + load_template)
        template = loader.get_template('admin/test_attempt.html') # 4
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


admin.site.register(Template, TemplateAdmin)  # 5
```

#### `# 1`

This is the template that will be used when you click through to inspect or change (or add for that matter) a particular instance of a model that you have. If you are going to have a link to your new view, you will need to change this template and add a link in to whatever url you define at `# 3`. By the way, if all you want to do is to customise this view, you can ignore everything else, all you need to do is add what you need to that template.

#### `# 2`

You need to understand why we are having to use `get_urls`. Normally to return a particular view, you set something up in `urls.py` which will point to a particular view, that you have (normally defined somewhere like `views.py`). However we are wanting to add an `admin` view, and all of the urls starting `admin/...` are dealt with inside the admin app. To get around this django provides us with the `get_urls` method in `ModelAdmin`, so we can add in extra views.

#### `# 3`

`self.admin_view()` just adds in some additional logic about authorization, so that we don't have to worry about that. Note in the line above, we only need to add the end part of the url, so the full url will be admin/app/model//test

#### `# 4`

This is where we define your extra view, it makes sense to add the view as a method of this ModelAdmin since it relates directly to it.

#### `# 5`

In the tutorial you were following, the writer must have some model called `Template` (which is perhaps a pretty confusing name for a model), and you need to replace `Template` with whatever model you are making this view for). It also makes sense to rename `TemplateAdmin` to something more appropriate (if your model is called `Car` call it `CarAdmin`).

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Following the link you added in the comment below, I am guessing you are trying to achieve the tasks outlined here: https://github.com/ganeshkbhat/pr/blob/master/admintmpl/admin.py. Namely:

```
# TASK:
# need custom admin template inside admin that shows
#       all questions assigned to user
#       filter option sort by user

# TASK:
# Create test template which shows inside admin
#       1. question
#           - INLINE options - 2 answers (4 options max)
#       2. question
#           - INLINE options - 2 answers (4 options max)
#       Submit
# On submit save to QuestionsAnswered
```

These tasks can all be achieved without anything very custom at all, definitely not the kind of thing that is needed in the tutorial that you have been following. I'm not going to answer this all here, because it goes way beyond what this question is asking. But I would advise you to look at the django docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/ They provide an exlanation as to how to do all of the things you need.

Comment: Can I know who is this? It's a time taken reply.

Comment: self.admin_view() does this api allow us to create a new view to admin site or it is outside the site? If it is outside the site, do you expect me to add authentication in template line other admin template authentication or extend any template or is authenticated template needed since the url created can be accessed directly if outside admin app?

Comment: Second, if I need this link to be accessed by the dashboard in admin along with view/edit options do I need to customise the template. Is that what I am supposed to do? Or the redirect is supposed to be automatic if I add a redirect statement for the list view of the extended+modified listview admin template.

Comment: The flow is Admin Dashboard (has link for form) > click on this link > goes to form > fill form with data from different models AssignedQuestions (inline Questions+Answers) > Submit > Takes back to dashboard or ListView based on submit action.

Comment: Does this flow make the registered admin template outside of django admin which needs authentication based on above answer or I need user authetication for this like django created apps? I understand that I can extend the admin base template but unsure if that would work with authentication. I have not try your answer yet. I just saw your reply

Comment: The problem I am facing was when I was trying to do the custom admin template creation it was not finding the template function in admin site when importing. It was giving me template function not found error in django 3.x. pProbably an issue with import? What si the import statement for the custom template function creation, if needed. Thats part of my actual question since I faced issues with this. Django throws error saying there is no custom template registration function when I try to import it. Why so? Does creating/registering custom template not work or not possible?

Comment: `from django.templates import Template`. This is the line where errors were thrown saying cannot find this and second in some cases some xyz usage is wrong. I don't remember it was month or two back

Answer (score 3):

The blog that you are referring to will be confusing to even an experienced Django developer. It has very small code snippets, so you're obviously totally confused about the missing bits of code. For example

1. This line that you added is incorrect: `from django.templates import Template  # THIS IS WRONG!`

`Template` here is the 'model' class that the blog author has created (it's also not a good name for a model – it's too generic). So basically you'll have something like this in your models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Template(models.Model):
    some_model_field = models.CharField()
    ...
```

Then in your admin you can do `from .models import Template`.

2. The section about `CustomAdminSite` in the blogpost isn't essential to creating custom template, and will just confuse you.
3. In any case, you've to list the apps under `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py. You can't remove them from there.
4. You are also confusing the nomenclature: Templates and (Django) Apps are entirely different concepts. The idea of Templates & Views is the same whether you are customizing the Django Admin or custom webpages. Django Admin is just a custom helper site that Django provides. You can definitely customize the Django Admin and don't have to create custom webpages external to the Django Admin. However you'll have have to work within the Django Admin architecture.

[Here](https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-add-custom-action-buttons-to-django-admin-8d266f5b0d41)'s a much better blog post that might be somewhat related to what you're doing. I would suggest you undo the things you did and start afresh.

Answer (score -1):

first argument of admin.site.register() should be a model class

I think this code will work for you

```
@admin.register(yourmodelclass)
class yourmodelclassAdmin(ModelAdmin):
   change_list_template = 'admin/test_attempt.html'
```

Comment: I tried this. Doesn't work for me. I also have online's. Will that have an effect? Surprisingly one to many relationship doesn't work at all. Leave alone getting inlines I faced this while doing the template

Comment: https://github.com/ganeshkbhat/pr/blob/master/admintmpl/models.py is what I am using.